# SVN Commit Issue

Tags: eclipse, svn, commit

Whenever I commit some code to my SVN repository and then do a Synchronization again with the repository the "Team Synchronizing" panel shows me that there is a update to be taken on my code and it shows 0 files and just an "empty update" to update to the latest revision number (the revision number of the recent code commit which I did) in the eclipse. I am on Windows 7. I have used the same tools in Mac and it works fine. Whenever I do a commit in Mac Eclipse it automatically updates it self.

Is this a bug or is there something I am missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that although you have Eclipse on both Mac and Windows, the SVN plugin, or the SVN connector used by that plugin, is different between your two setups.

I'm afraid I don't have details to hand, but have seen this behaviour before. The SVN integration in Eclipse makes most sense if you end up with no incoming changes after you do a commit. It seems one of the Eclipse plugins decides after commit to immediately poll for any outstanding changes. It sees that the top-level folder for your project has been updated, so marks it for update.

This is an accurate reflection of what happens in SVN - if you commit a new revision is created in the repository, but your local checkout is not at that revision until you do an update. If you run "svn info" on the command line just after a commit you will see this.